# $rootScope.$watchCollection is not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use $rootScope.$watchCollection in my code to update the data in controller B from controller A . but i am not getting any successful in it. as my application got stuck at this point ,so i am seeking your help so that i can came to know that where i am going wrong in code.

Controller B :-

```js
 app.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, LocalStorage, $stateParams,
      $rootScope) {
     $scope.user = {};
     $scope.user.userName = LocalStorage.getData("userName");
     $scope.user.profilePic = LocalStorage.getData("userProfile");

     $rootScope.$watchCollection(function(n, o) {
      if (n !== o) {
       var list = $rootScope.wholecartList;
       alert("Length " + list.length);
      }
     });
    });
```

Controller A :-

```js
app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($http, $scope, $ionicPopup, $state,
  $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, DataService, LocalStorage, $stateParams,
  ProductId, DuplicateCheck, $rootScope) {
 $scope.productList = DataService.getProducts();

 $scope.getProductId = function(productId) {
  ProductId.addProductId(productId);
  $state.go("app.products-details");

 }
 var cartList = [];
 $scope.cartListItems = function(product) {
  if (cartList.length > 0) {
   if (!DuplicateCheck.getProducts(product.product_id, cartList)) {
    cartList.push(product);
   }
  } else {
   cartList.push(product);
  }
  $rootScope.wholecartList = cartList;
 }

});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: You need to add some more code - for now it is unclear what and when is called. However, $rootScope.$watchCollection(function(n, o) { if (n !== o) { << this is strange: you log only when object changes, i.e. if I just add object to array - your log wont trigger... So then you should use usual $watch.

Comment: Hey petr , thanks for your reply , but i really does'nt get your point ..are you clear with my question ...i just want to display count in menu html and the list will be passing from productCtrl , this list containes the number of items selected by user , so i just want to show the count in my ui on cart image which is in menu.html file.

Answer (score 0):

After this you need to update the $rootScope (say, run the apply cycle);

```js
app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($http, $scope, $ionicPopup, $state,
  $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, DataService, LocalStorage, $stateParams,
  ProductId, DuplicateCheck, $rootScope) {
 $scope.productList = DataService.getProducts();

 $scope.getProductId = function(productId) {
  ProductId.addProductId(productId);
  $state.go("app.products-details");

 }
 var cartList = [];
 $scope.cartListItems = function(product) {
  if (cartList.length > 0) {
   if (!DuplicateCheck.getProducts(product.product_id, cartList)) {
    cartList.push(product);
   }
  } else {
   cartList.push(product);
  }
  $rootScope.wholecartList = cartList;
                updateRootScope();
 }

        function updateRootScope(){
            if(!$rootScope.$$phase){
                $rootScope.$apply();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Hey iLoveJS, thanks for your reply ,after putting your code i am getting white screen

Comment: Are there any more issues, or is that the expected page?

Comment: no there is not any other issue except this , i am just trying to send the list to controller B on every button click in product Html so that i can show the count on menu html that how many items does cartlist contains.

Comment: Moreover when i am trying to print the value using alert its showing me undefined i.e alert($rootScope.wholecartList);..its coming  undefined

Comment: First: from html you can get the length as:
<span>{{$root.wholecartList.length}}</span> OR <span ng-bind="$root.wholecartList.length"></span>

Comment: Second: I am not sure why $rootScope.wholecartList comes as undefined, if you update a sample code on fiddle, may be we can work out a way.